# 2 references to same object in object - Multiplicity is not valid in Role in relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I have a User.cs:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User : BaseUser, IBaseUser
{
    [Key]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public int CreatedById { get; set; } = 0;

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")]
    public int ModifiedById { get; set; } = 0;

    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }


    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; } = null;

    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; } = null;
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

I'd like to have a CreatedBy and ModifiedBy navigation property to the User object that created and modified this User object.

However, when I launch my application, I receive this error on my 'LogDb' (derived from DbContext) Database.Initialize(true) function call:

> User_ModifiedBy_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'User_ModifiedBy_Target' in relationship 'User_ModifiedBy'.  Because
>   the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper
>   bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

I've tried a lot of things, but can't seem to have the result I want.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? (if possible, with data annotations)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll need to step away from Data Annotations to do this bit:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.CreatedBy).WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.ModifiedBy).WithMany();
}
```

You may also want to define `CreatedById` and `ModifiedById` as `int?` so they can be nullable, or you'll never be able to create your first user!